# How to make a gem available that isn't listed in Gemfile

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler, gemfile

I made a [gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/pbcopy) for myself to use in the console. I want to be able to use it all the time everywhere.

I can't figure out how to get Bundler to recognize it without putting it into my Gemfile, but that requires the rest of the people on my team to know about it and have it installed.

Is there a way to get Bundler to overlay a Gemfile of my choosing? Or to somehow generally make my gem available to me even though it is not listed in my Gemfile?

Answer (score 1):

You could circumvent bundler by putting this at the end of the Gemfile and gitignore the Gemfile.dev.rb:

```
dev_gemfile = File.expand_path("Gemfile.dev.rb", File.dirname(__FILE__))
instance_eval(File.read(dev_gemfile)) if File.exists?(dev_gemfile)
```

Your Gemfile.lock will not match on different developers' machines if their Gemfile.dev.rb didn't match but I'm only concerned with exact matches in production.  Minor changes between developers and production are already an issue if you have multiple platforms and can be worked around in the same way.